# How can I make a button tag to expand?

Tags: html, css, button, stylesheet, styling

I'm having troubles styling this piece of html code:

```
<div class="item-buttons">
    <a href="/some/url/with/value/1417">Sample button link</a>
    <button class="some-class some-status" value="1417">Button</button>
    <a href="/some/url/with/value/385">Other link</a>
</div>
```

This code, given the CSS rules below, will get shown as a box with buttons. The buttons represented with an `<a>` tag will just behave as normal links while the `<button>` buttons have a more complex behavior and need to store some state information in their class attribute and in the `value`  attribute. That's why I don't use an `<a>` tag for them.

This is the CSS that is applied to them:

```
.item-buttons {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 0px;
width: 130px;
}

.item-buttons a, .item-buttons button {
background: #eee;
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
display: block;
padding: 6px 8px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
font-size: 12px;

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#f5f5f5));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f5f5f5);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f5f5f5);
background-color: #f5f5f5;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#.item-buttons a:hover, .item-buttons button:hover {
background: #a2e249;
color: #3d640e;
}
```

And here's [the whole example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48j8m/). As you can see, the `<a>` and `<button>` buttons look very much the same, except that the `<button>` ones don't expand as the `<a>` ones do. I want them all to expand. I've tried several CSS rules to no avail. Can you help me to solve this and make the `<button>` buttons expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.item-buttons a, .item-buttons button{width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the button class to this instruction it seems to work. It is what you expected ?

```
.some-class {
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: While this works in JSFiddle, it doesn't in my project. The button expands a little, but not as much as it should. Anon's answer does works. Thanks anyways.